# HTML Image going across entire screen

Tags: html, css

So I have this div element

```
    <footer><div id="foot-er" style="background-image: url(images/Home/space.gif); height: 190px; width: 1349px; border: 1px solid black; line-height:1.7em;"></div></footer>

    // CSS
    #foot-er
    {

    }
```

This image does not stretch across the entire screen, leaving white around the image. I tried researching this up in google but only found how to not cut off the image and show the full image. My problem here is not that the image is being cut off, but it won't stretch across the entire screen.

[image]

The space stary image is the div image. The orange/blue image is the body background. How would I get the div image to stretch and cover the body image.

Comment: You're going to want to use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Use `width: 100%` and `background-size: cover` instead? With a pixel width it will either be too narrow to cover a very wide screen, or force an overflow on a narrow screen.

Comment: width:100%
and
        background-size:cover;
still do the same thing as below.

Comment: Does your parent element have a padding or a margin?

Comment: The parent element is

        <footer>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** This problem is caused by the margin on the body element

### What are the default properties on the body element

According to the [w3c default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html#body-display), the body element includes the following css

```
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px; }
body:focus {
  outline: none; }
```

These properties make it easier to read text without any formatting as the text isn't touching the sides of the browser window, the same as a book

### What has the default properties to do with the problem of the image not sticking to the footer

Because of the "margin: 8px;" attached to the body, all elements inside the body will have a gap of 8px between them and the edge of the browser window.
While this gap is created by design by the draft of html, it will become problematic because it prevents puttings things against the side of the browser window.

### How can this problem be solved

This problem can be solved by 1 of the following solutions:

### Removing the margin on the body element

By using the following css code

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

You can remove the margin from the html, allowing you webapp to touch sides of the screen. however, this has its drawbacks, namely:

- You need add margins/paddings to your design to prevent it from touching the sides where it decreases readability

```css
body { margin: 0px; }

p {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#image {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <div id=image></div>
</body>
```

### Use absolute/fixed positioning on the image

By using absolute/fixed positioning on you image, you can force the place where the image is rendered to the correct cordinates.
This can be done by doing:

```
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This has its advantages that you have a footer that is always at the bottom of the page, no matter how large your browser is. This also comes with its own disadvantages, these include:

- If the text above the image is to large, it will flow under the picture before creating a scroll bar, these can be countered by adding "margin-bottom: 100px;" to your body element so the text will leave a bigger cap at the bottom of the page

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


#image {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <div id=image></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Dang, thanks for all the information! This worked for me. However, I do have one question, I use position:relative; on the div elements in <section>, should I keep that and use position:absolute? or just use position:absolute; Sorry for such late reply, was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
<div id="foot-er" style="background:url(001.png); height: 190px; width: 1349px; border: 1px solid black; line-height:1.7em;background-size:100% 190px"></div>
```

`background-size:100% 190px`

100% is width and 190px is image height and this will stretch your images.

Comment: This zoomed in the image for me, not make it stretch across the screen. I would post a picture but it says I need 10 reputation points.

Comment: This did stretch the image but it still stays in the same position not covering across the screen like I want.

Comment: Well it stretched the image, but not across the entire screen.
Look at my post above for the way it looks, editting the image

Comment: *{margin:0,padding:0} add this in your css.

Comment: I tried this on the div element and it did nothing. When I do it on the body however, it does what I want but on ALL the div elements, I only want it to do that on one.