# HTML body margin 0 messing up div positioning

Tags: html, css

I am a bite confused on what is happening here. I put my body margin set to 0 in my css and then all the div elements stretch across the screen like I want, but I want this to apply for only one. From a previous question: [HTML Image going across entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581600/html-image-going-across-entire-screen)

An answer said to use position:absolute and then change the position of the div elements. I used to have position:relative on these div elements and when I changed that to absolute, it combined all the div elements in one position. I tried moving them with bottom:then whatever pixels, but still did not move it at all. Would this be the way to move it? What would I do? On W3 schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

It tells me a lot about positioning div elements, but when I tried to use this it did not work on one div element I tried, but instead overlapped it.

How would I move these div elements?

Code CSS

```
#middle-4{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:8;
    bottom:0;
    top:-800px;}
```

Code HTML

```
    <div id="middle-4" style="background-image: url(images/Home/rock.png); height: 540px; width: 1348px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

This is done so for as you can see up to 4 div elements.

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with HTML and CSS that we can't see. Please post an example of the problematic code.

Comment: Code added, tell me if you need the other div elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want all element to conform to the default `body` margin except one element (or multiple elements using a class).

I would do it like this...

- Give `body` a specific margin to ensure it is consistent across browsers.
- Use negative horizontal margins to pull your element outside of the constraints of `body`

```css
body {
    margin: 8px;
    background: lightGreen;
}
div {
    background: lightBlue;
    padding: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.fullwidth {
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm constrained by body</div>
<div class="fullwidth">I'm full width</div>
<div>I'm constrained by body</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works for me and does what I want. Thank you, but there is one problem. On my footer div element it hits the bottom of the page obviously, the margin on the left and right work but how would I do a margin for the bottom? I tried margin-bottom:-8px; but didn't work. Besides that, everything else works. I also tried just plain margin:-8px; on the footer, still the same as margin left and right.

Comment: An easy fix for that would be to add `margin-bottom: 0;` to your `body` or to combine it with the above you would write `body { margin: 8px 8px 0 8px }`

Answer (score 1):

Setting margin on body only ensures cross-browser consistency as mentioned by uʍopǝpısdn

If you have 4 divs containing an image each, you should stick to position: relative - this will line up the divs / images vertically on top of each other.

Your issue might have to do with image sizes - if you want all images to keep their original size, you can keep their attributes for width and height as specified in your example "middle-4": height: 540px; width: 1348px;

However - do you want one div / image to stretch across the width of body / screen, you will have to apply the size in percentage - this can be done in 2 ways:

CSS3 - you have the options of "cover" or "contain", which can be applied to div as youre doing it now - example:

```
div  {
    background: url(images/Home/rock.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

CSS2 - you can apply a class to the image itself, and forget about the surrounding div - example:

```
<img src="images/Home/rock.png" class="img_width" /> 

.img_width {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
}
```

Comment: I already had the divs to position:relative, but thanks for the information.